# Error while installing mangodb in mac m1 to run laravel project

Tags: mongodb

while trying to install mangodb for php laravel i have tried to install it doing

```
 % sudo pecl install mongodb
```

where as i am getting error

```
 nssl.c:24:10: fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found
 #include <openssl/sha.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1 error generated.
 make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-crypto-openssl.lo] Error 1
 ERROR: `make' failed
```

my OS Details are : ProductName: macOS ProductVersion: 14.3 BuildVersion: 23D56

unix variant local 23.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.3.0: Wed Dec 20 21:30:27 PST 2023; root:xnu-10002.81.5~7/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 x86_64

i have done the terminal command : $ sudo pecl install mongodb

this is from this site : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php-drivers/

where as i am stucked in with the error nssl.c:24:10: fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found #include <openssl/sha.h> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-crypto-openssl.lo] Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed

i have found a work around as such

cd /usr/local/include ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl . from this site https://www.anintegratedworld.com/mac-osx-fatal-error-opensslsha-h-file-not-found/#comments

it says : Apple deprecated its OpenSSL shared libraries a while back (with OS X 10.7). That’s because OpenSSL doesn’t offer release-to-release binary compatibility, so we can’t update the shared libraries to the latest OpenSSL without breaking all the existing clients.

but i even don't have include folder in my mac ... please help

Comment: try your luck on stackexchange.com https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87458/make-fatal-error-openssl-sha-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

Got the help...

brew install libssl-dev && brew install pkg-config

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768715/i-am-getting-error-fatal-error-openssl-sha-h-file-not-found-while-installin/768769#768769